# state update doesn't get reflected in console.log()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

I have a component where I am decrementing a value contained in a state variable, every second, using a useState hook :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FC } from "react";

interface ITimerProps {
  remainingSeconds: number;
}

const Timer: FC<ITimerProps> = ({ remainingSeconds = 10 }) => {
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(remainingSeconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      decrementTime();
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [remainingSeconds]);

  function decrementTime  (): void  {
  
    if (remainingTime > 0) {
      setRemainingTime((currentTime) => currentTime - 1);
    }
   console.log("function gets called, state is : " + remainingTime);
  };

  return <div>{remainingTime}</div>;
};

export default Timer;
```

`remainingTime` ,which gets rendered, is indeed decremented every second, and in the developer tools, I can see that the state is updating.
But the `console.log()` inside the `decrementTime` function always display a value of 10.

The `if` statement within `decrementTime` function also always checks `true`, as it seems that when being read within this function, the state is always 10.

Is there something that I'm missing here ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the function itself that you are calling in the `setInterval` is not updating. You have to append that function to the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook. in order to avoid the eslint warning wrap the `decrementTime` function with the `useCallback` hook (doesn't make a difference because the function will change anyway on every render in that case).

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FC } from "react";

interface ITimerProps {
  remainingSeconds: number;
}

const Timer: FC<ITimerProps> = ({ remainingSeconds = 10 }) => {
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(remainingSeconds);

  const decrementTime = useCallback(() => {
    if (remainingTime > 0) {
      setRemainingTime((currentTime) => currentTime - 1);
    }
    console.log("function gets called, state is : " + remainingTime);
  }, [remainingTime]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      decrementTime();
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [remainingSeconds, decrementTime]);

  return <div>{remainingTime}</div>;
};

export default Timer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `decrementTime` function declaration from an arrow function to `function decrementTime(){}` for it to get hoisted and added it in the `useEffect` dependency array, now I get the correct behavior :

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FC } from "react";

interface ITimerProps {
  remainingSeconds: number;
}

const Timer: FC<ITimerProps> = ({ remainingSeconds = 10 }) => {
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(remainingSeconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      decrementTime();
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [remainingSeconds,decrementTime]);

  function decrementTime(): void {
    if (remainingTime > 0) {
      setRemainingTime((currentTime) => currentTime - 1);
    }
    console.log("function gets called, state is : " + remainingTime);
  }

  return <div>{remainingTime}</div>;
};

export default Timer;
```